# Laravel / Redis transaction

Tags: laravel, redis, transactions, locking

I'm using Redis in Laravel, but I'm not sure how Redis handles global locks. I have a 'global' key that can only be accessed and updated per request. When a request is using and updating the key, other requests must wait until the key is released.

Here is an example of how I'm currently handling the key:

```
$value = json_decode(Redis::get('key'), true);
$value['counter'] = $value['counter'] + 1;
Redis::set('key', json_encode($value));
```

My question is: does Redis automatically lock the key during processing, or do we need to handle it manually?

Comment: There is an entire section on the database about `atomic locks` on the documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/cache#atomic-locks. Using `Redis::get` and `Redis::set`, you are NOT locking anything...

Answer (score 0):

This action is so common in Redis it has built in functionality for what you are doing. Therefor you can call `incr`, see the [documentation](https://redis.io/commands/incr/). This require you to avoid deserializing and serializing your data, but to be honest that data should be saved in a more persistent storage, than the cache in my opinion.

```
$yourModel = YourModel::find(1);

Redis::incr('model-counter-' . $yourModel->id);

Redis::decr('model-counter-' . $yourModel->id);

Redis::get('model-counter-' . $yourModel->id);
```

Redis is by default [operating sequentially](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/best-practices-redis-clients-and-amazon-elasticache-for-redis/).

> where incoming client requests are handled sequentially

Comment: Hi @mrhn "Redis is by default operating sequentially", It means there is no commands from other clients will be processed until the connection is closed, right? For example, we have two clients A and B, when client A (init a connection before client B) sends a "get" command, client B sends "set" command, then the client A sends "set" command, the Redis will process both "get" and "set" commands of client A before process the "set" command of the client B because the client A got the connection before the client B, right?

Comment: That's why you should use incr, then it is a single operation and there is no race condition. Or else redis has transaction feature, but i have no experience in that. Compare to how the inital solution is presented i would also feel that is overkill instead of using the features that are present, with a different data model.